# Sentinel-2 projection shift

Tags: coordinate-system, remote-sensing, sentinel-2

I recently observe a shift in the geographic projection of Sentinel 2 data. Please see the screenshots below for clarification (Granule T33UXP, Band 8 only). The first image was taken on 20160314, the second (shifted) on 20160403. I added a polygon as a reference. 
This is unprocessed data as downloaded from the API hub.
S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_SGS__20160314T171554_A003794_T33UXP_N02.01
S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_SGS__20160403T152610_A004080_T33UXP_N02.01

Does anyobdy else observe this? Is this a known issue or does it occur just in my particular case?

[image: 20160314]
[image: 20160403]

Comment: Can you write the image/granule number of these two images?

Comment: Yes, that should be included, thanks. I added the information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've downloaded these granules and notice the same shift. It appears to be geographic processing error on ESA's behalf. 
I've never encountered a shift like this before. The image metadata is the same for both, which means some error occurred before the Level 1-C product. (the 100*100Km granules have already been processed, for more information [look here](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-products))

I would suggest [contacting ESA](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/help), maybe even on [social media](https://twitter.com/CopernicusEU) and let them know about this error. Nn several occasions before they've halted the data dissemination on the Pre-ops hub and its API due to processing errors. The shifted image is pretty recent, and might have yet to be noticed.

Comment: I can send the link to a colleague at ESA, but the best way would be to duplicate this post on Sentinel forum : 
http://forum.step.esa.int/c/s2tbx

Comment: I was thinking about posting this on the s2tbx forum but i think it's off-topic since it doens't concern the toolbox. I might do it anyway just to disseminate the information.

Comment: Done: http://forum.step.esa.int/t/sentinel-2-projection-shift-error/1914

Answer (score 4):

the anomaly has been identified and is currently under investigation.
It is not systematic as far as we know.
Please report this kind of anomaly to the [Copernicus help desk](http://land.copernicus.eu/global/contactpage).

Thanks
Sébatien CLERC
S2 Mission Performance Center

Answer (score 0):

Check the other granules in the scene from which 33UXP is taken.

If it is something systematic, it should affect all granules (in zone UTM33).

Comment: yes, it effects all granules in the scene. I also checked for UTM35, the problem doens't occur there. (At least for 20160404T132741_A004094_T35TLL)